# Downloading pdf files from google drive using wget

Tags: ubuntu, wget

I have a google drive link with the following url  `https://drive.google.com/file/d/13f1a4u_HC63izsZWhaJge0G7adqkDPuO/view`

I tried `wget    https://drive.google.com/file/d/13f1a4u_HC63izsZWhaJge0G7adqkDPuO/view`

but i couldnt download anything.How to use wget to download.I am using Ubuntu.Please help me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this.. soman raj

```
  wget --no-check-certificate 'https://docs.google.com/uc?export=download&id=13f1a4u_HC63izsZWhaJge0G7adqkDPuO' -O geometryandalgebra.pdf
```